# Does windows insider not support multiple languages now?

Tags: windows-11, language-pack, windows-insider

The windows system that came with my computer is `Windows 11 Home Chinese Edition`, which makes my computer only display in Simplified Chinese.

There are some errors reported in Chinese that prevent me from searching the web in English. I used to be able to make my computer switch languages freely by turning on the `windows insider` option, but recently I reinstalled my computer and found that even though I turned on the insider, it still says `Your Windows license supports only one display language`.
Is it a change in windows 11 policy, or is there some setting I'm overlooking?

Comment: You have an edition installed that only supports a single language pack.  The fact you have opted into and installed an Insider Preview build does not change that fact. Insider Preview build installations have always, since the program's inception, required a valid Windows license. Upgrade to an edition that does not have the same limitation.